# Core Data iPhone - Loading a String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, load, nsfetchrequest

I am having troubles with understanding how to load data with Core Data. This is what I have:

Entity named 'People'
Attributes of this entity named 'firstName' (string), 'lastName' (string), 'isSpecial' (boolean), 'isVerySpecial' (boolean).

I want to get the first and last name of any person who is special or very special so that I can then put those names into labels and wherever I like as I wish. I have played about with fetch requests without luck.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *weightEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[[yourCoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:weightEntity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSpecial == %@ OR isVerySpecial == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [[yourCoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

And then:

```
Person *person = [result objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lastName = person.lastName;
NSString *firstName = person.firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Person fetchAllSortedBy:@"lastName" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSpecial == %@ OR isVerySpecial == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]] groupBy:nil delegate:self];
```

then you will get an array of persons in your fetchedResultsController. To get it simple use

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects];
```

Hope it helps